# Loop through string variable names in R

Tags: r, loops, variables, names

i have to do the following calculations a hundred times, starting with art1 and ending with art250:

`sd_art1_2008 <- sd(c(art1_1_2008,art1_2_2008,art1_3_2008,art1_4_2008,art1_5_2008,art1_6_2008,art1_7_2008,art1_8_2008,art1_9_2008))`

`sd_art2_2008 <- sd(c(art2_1_2008,art2_2_2008,art2_3_2008,art2_4_2008,art2_5_2008,art2_6_2008,art2_7_2008,art2_8_2008,art2_9_2008))`
... and so on..

I tried to interate through this with

```
   paste("sd_art",i,"_2008", sep="") <-sd(c("art",i,"_1_2008","art",i,"_2_2008")))
   }
```

,but it errors. Does anyone maybe know how to solve this?
Best regards, Daniel

Comment: hi, welcome to SO! 1) you use paste instead of paste0 which will not work here because paste, withoud further arguments, will add spaces which paste0 won't. 2) you try to generate names where you dont need to, 3) you use the paste command for the name creation but not for the actual data -> if at all it should be `sd(c(paste0("art",i,_1_2008", paste0("art",i,"_2_2008")))` not that i think this would work as you intend. i suggest looking at the apply-functions (especially `lapply()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have such 100's of vectors lying around in the global environment. As you have noticed it becomes very difficult to manage them or perform any calculation on them. R provides data structure to manage such objects, put them in a list or a dataframe.

However, considering the problem at hand you can search for all the variables in global environment using `ls`, you can also specify a pattern to find objects with similar name etc. So we create variables `art1`, `art2`....`art250` using `paste0`. We find all the variables that have a particular pattern in them and take `sd` of them and return a vector.

```
result <- sapply(paste0('art', 1:250, '_'), function(x) 
             sd(unlist(mget(ls(pattern = x, envir = .GlobalEnv),
                       .GlobalEnv)), na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

You can try it with this example :

```
art1_1_2008 <- 1
art1_2_2008 <- 5
art2_1_2008 <- 6
art2_2_2008 <- 8

result <- sapply(paste0('art', 1:2), function(x) 
              sd(unlist(mget(ls(pattern = x, envir = .GlobalEnv), 
                 .GlobalEnv)), na.rm = TRUE))
result
#    art1     art2 
#2.828427 1.414214 

#Confirm values are correct by checking manually. 
sd(c(1, 5))
#[1] 2.828427
sd(c(6, 8))
#[1] 1.414214
```

Comment: it works until art10, after that the calculation is not correct anymore. I belive it is because this function issues with art1 and art10 . Do you know how adapt your function that it can deal with this? Vg Daniel

Comment: @sdaniel24 yes, sorry. I missed that. Can you check the updated answer? I added `'_'` in `paste0`.

Comment: hi Ronak thank you very much, this now does exactly what I need :-)